# What is the best way to perform a complex refactoring spanning multiple repositories?

Tags: git

I need to re-organize a project using git. This project currently has 3 separate (central) repositories and I will need to move a large number of files back and forth between them. While doing this, there is development going on on each repository, and the restructuring will take some time. I have been continuously rebasing my refactor branches from master in each respective repository.

Is there an established way of doing this sort of complex cross repository refactoring in a way that preserves the history across repositories and takes advantage of git's rename merge logic across repositories, by say moving all repos into a third one, do the merge and move back?

Effectively, I have three repositories, A, B, and C. I want to move files from B to A and C and preserve history. This is not a simple move of one directory, but a large number of individual files being moved to new locations, renamed, updated etc. I have been working across A, B, and C, moving and updating files, but this will obviously not keep the history of the files being moved across repositories. I imagine that it would be possible to create a new repository D, import A, B, and C into sub directories, rebase to merge the individual commits on A, B, and C into one new big commit on D that will make git understand that files have been moved across, not just removed in one place and deleted from another, then apply the changes back to each individual repository?

Comment: This is a little vague.  What advice might we be able to offer, beyond "use sensible branching?"  Perhaps you could explain your problem a bit more clearly and specifically.

Comment: Updated question to clarify.

Comment: Why is all this moving around required?  Do you have development branches, release branches, etc?  Do you dogfood?

Answer (score 1):

You could take repo B, clone it, do all modifications you want to change the files (move locations, rename, update, etc) to prepare the files for repository A. You could also use `filter-branch` to rewrite history deleting unwanted paths/files. When it is ready, you could fetch it as a branch from repository A. Then you just merge the branch into A master branch. Yes, git could merge branches from different repositories, it makes a history look funny - two roots (initial commits) are merged at some point.

Then do the same with repo C.

Comment: Yep, my case is similar..however I also want to be able to re-sync any later changes from the original repos to the destination. I was thinking to run all my restructuring again using a script, then merge this again. Is this possible without mad conflicts?

Comment: @inger Wow, it could be quite cumbersome. However, as git tracks file contents, not particular file path, probably cherry-picking would work (but for changed files only, not newly added or removed) if the changes are not too broad in file(s). Unfortunately it is quite unreliable, so avoid such work-flow if possible. Describe the requirements you have more detailed, better as a new question. Probably you could use http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Subtree-Merging .

Comment: Many thanks for the quick reply. The context is,there were 2 product lines in repos A,B - new I merged these into C (after some restructuring: mv, rm); however A,B should is still alive for a while.Initially I thought I'd git subtree using a script triggered by commit.However I don't want to increase level of hierarchies.Anyway now (I hope) I reduced the problem to just keeping a "reorg" branch in sync with the master, repeated applying same mv/rms on master.The only reason for conflicts is that the merge-base in before the old structure,even though the merged structures match..